# Jupyter refuses to load virtual environment in VS Code interactive mode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, python-venv, virtual-environment

After getting `ModuleNotFoundError` when trying to load packages in python interactive mode in VS Code, I now suspect that the current virtual environment is not loading correctly when in the Jupyter Kernel, although I have selected it in the upper right dropdown (see screenshot).

[image: selected environment]

I therefore ran a cell with

```
import os
os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
```

and got

```
import os...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\aig\decoding_methods.py in 
      2 import os
----> 3 os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']

C:\Python37\lib\os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    679         except KeyError:
    680             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 681             raise KeyError(key) from None
    682         return self.decodevalue(value)
    683 

KeyError: 'VIRTUAL_ENV'
```

indicating that the virtual environment indeed is not loading. There's no problem loading the environment and the modules in the console. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you should use `try/except` to catch this error or you should use `os.getenv('VIRTUAL_ENV')` and you will get `None` if there is no `'VIRTUAL_ENV'` in system.

Comment: as for me: correct path to venv has nothing to do with `'VIRTUAL_ENV'` - value `'VIRTUAL_ENV'` can be set in different way or maybe it needs to use `active` for this venv

Comment: It was just intended as a test to see if a `venv` is used, since I wasn't sure if the `ModuleNotFoundError` was due to this. No error is raised when I run this from a regular jupyter notebook, further indicating that the problem lies within vs code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to re-install the kernel, but specifying the `--name` flag:

So first:
`pip install ipykernel` followed by

`python -m ipykernel install --user --name=myenv`

[Source](https://anbasile.github.io/posts/2017-06-25-jupyter-venv/)

Answer (score 0):

When I use the global python environment, VS Code displays the information you described:

[image]

When I use the created virtual environment, it shows the correct information:

[image]

Therefore, please use the virtual environment described in this document, which can be well recognized by VS Code: [Virtual environment in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments).

Comment: I'm not using the global environment, but a virtual environment as shown in the first screenshot in my post. The problem is, that the jupyter kernel doesn't seem to load the virtual environment, but somehow defaults to the global env. The interpreter however seems to have no problem with loading the virtual env.

Comment: @Comfort Eagle  -How was the virtual environment you used to create? Please try to use the command "python3 -m venv .venv" in VS Code to create a virtual environment.